# Spring MVC convert Spring Rest Api

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa

I have a spring mvc project, i want to convert spring rest api project.

Here my sample codes;

My Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/student")
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;

    @Autowired
    private SchoolService schoolService;
    @GetMapping("/list")
    public String ListStudents(Model model) {

        List<Student> theStudent = studentService.getStudents();
        model.addAttribute("students", theStudent);

        return "List-student";
    }

    @GetMapping("/addNewStudent")
    public String addNewStudent(Model model) {

        Student theStudent = new Student();
        model.addAttribute("student", theStudent);

        List<School> theSchool = schoolService.getSchools();
        model.addAttribute("schools", theSchool);
        return "student-form";
    }

    @PostMapping("/saveStudent")
    public String saveStudent(@ModelAttribute("student") Student theStudent) {

        studentService.saveStudent(theStudent);

        return "redirect:/student/list";
    }

    @GetMapping("/showFormforUpdate")
    public String showFormForUpdate(@RequestParam("studentID") int theId, Model model) {

        Student theStudent = studentService.getStudent(theId);
        model.addAttribute(theStudent);
        List<School> theSchool = schoolService.getSchools();
        model.addAttribute("schools", theSchool);
        return "student-form";

    }

    @GetMapping("/deleteStudent")
    public String deleteStudent(@RequestParam("studentID") int theId, Model model) {

        studentService.deleteStudent(theId);

        return "redirect:/student/list";
    }

}
```

My DAOImpl class

```
    @Repository
public class StudenDAOImpl implements StudentDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Student> getStudents() {

        Session currentSession=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query<Student> theQuery = currentSession.createQuery("from Student", Student.class);
        List<Student> students=theQuery.getResultList();
        return students;
    }


    @Override
    public void saveStudent(Student theStudent) {

        Session currentSession=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        currentSession.saveOrUpdate(theStudent);
    }


    @Override
    public Student getStudent(int theId) {

        Session currentSession=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Student theStudent=currentSession.get(Student.class, theId);

        return theStudent;
    }


    @Override
    public void deleteStudent(int theId) {
        Session currentSession=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query theQuery=currentSession.createQuery("delete from Student where id=:studentID");
        theQuery.setParameter("studentID", theId);
        theQuery.executeUpdate();

    }

}
```

Actually i know the places i need to change. But i don't know very well spring Rest Api. In my code i send many attributes in my view(jsp file) and i catch this attributes here . But RestApi does not have views. I need to delete attribute functions. But what can i add instead of attribute functions? I am new the RestApi please help me what should i do?

Comment: If you want to have a detailed guide, see my book https://www.infoq.com/minibooks/spring-boot-building-api-backend/ (Disclaimer: I am the author)

Answer (score 1):

welcome to stack overflow.

Rest APIs work like this:

- You expose an endpoint and a verb (for example GET at /students)
- Some client calls your endpoint (makes a call to the server that holds your app)
- Your server delegates the call to a controller function ( a function with a `@GetMapping("/students")` for example )
- The controller function sends a response to the client (With spring, your method returns an object or a ResponseEntity)

REST APIs receive requests , process said request (and request data if present) and tipically return some data with a status code that indicates if the operation was successful.

With spring you do something like this:

```
@GetMapping("/students")
ResponseEntity<List<Student>> listStudents() {
    List<Student> stds = getStudents(); // call some service or DB
    return new ResponseEntity<>(stds, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

When you make a GET request to /students, spring will delegate the handling of the request to the listStudents method which will get the students and return data.

REST APIs tipically work with JSON, so the list of students you'll be returning will be serialized into a json list.

If you want to customize the student json structure you can use Jackson:

```
public class Student {
    @JsonProperty("cool_name") private String name;
// getters and setter
}
```

A rest api does not work with views or JSP. They tipically work with http requests and responses.

If you're working with spring mvc instead of spring boot, check this article:
https://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-4-mvc-rest-example-json/

If you can use spring boot (which I highly recommend) , check this:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

You should also annotate your REST controllers with `@RestController` for them to automatically handle rest calls.

Hope this helps and welcome to stack overflow

Comment: Thank you my friend you gave me valuable informations,definitely i will do it. I want to ask one more thing. I have 2 entity class in my project. In spring mvc i connected my sql database with 2 xml files. Web.xml and spring-servlet.xml. What does replace in spring boot this xml files? I find it one of them application.properties file. But what does other file? Again thanks for helping :)

Comment: Buy the way i work with STS. In my spring mvc project i have a folder named Web-Content, and this 2 xml files inside of this folder. But in my Spring Boot Rest Api project i dont have this folder. I have a file named application.properties. I am very confused what should i do. I need to define my controller and Service classes. But where?